# Iam getting Error like Unfinished Stubbing Detected in Mockito , Iam using Mockito for mocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I am getting following exception while running the tests. I am using Mockito for mocking. The hints mentioned by Mockito library are not helping.

```
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

Here is my method:
From `ps.setString` I am unable to do code coverage. Can anyone help me?

---

```java
public class Dao{
    public int[][] batchInsertAll(Collection<UploadRequest> request, int batchSize, final String jobId) {
    
        int[][] updateAllCounts = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into tb_import(id,name) values("","")", request, batchSize,
                new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<UploadRequest>() {
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, UploadRequest argument) throws SQLException {
                        ps.setString(1, Id);
                       ps.setString(2, argument.getName());
        }}); return updateAllCounts
    }
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void batchInsertAll() {
    int batchSize = 1000;
    String jobId = "xyz";
    List<UploadRequest> fileData = new ArrayList<UploadRequest>();
    UploadRequest rowdata1 = new UploadRequest("1", "xyz");
    UploadRequest rowdata1 = new UploadRequest("1", "abc");
    fileData.add(rowdata1);
    fileData.add(rowdata2);
    int[][] updateAllCounts = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    try {

        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                PreparedStatement ps = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
                ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter bpss = invocation.getArgumentAt(1,
                        ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter.class);

                try {
                    bpss.setValues(ps, 1);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return updateAllCounts;

            }
        }).when(jdbcTemplate).batchUpdate(anyString(), fileData, 1000,
                any(ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter.class));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        assert (true);
    }
    mockDao.batchInsertAll(fileData, 1000, jobId);
}
```

Comment: we need to know the code of the class containing batchInsertAll in order to know how to get the mocked jdbcTemplate into that method, since it is being referenced from an external scope

Comment: Added the code of the class which contains batchInsertAll

Comment: I don't see where you defined any expectations or behavior for the `PreparedStatement` mock `ps`.  Mockito is going to complain to you if any of `ps`'s collaborators call it and you haven't got any behavior defined for those calls.

Comment: iam catching sqlException

Answer (score 0):

First you have to think - what is your goal here?

You wrote a class `Dao` and a method `batchInsertAll`. I would think you'd want to test that. If you want to test that though you need to actually call that method. Calling

```
mockDao.batchInsertAll(fileData, 1000, jobId);
```

makes it look, like you're just calling a mock you created to test it, which obviously will do nothing except do whatever you configured that mock to do.

Also, the catching of `Exception` with `assert(true)` will not do what you think it'll do - this is a base Java assertion used for sanity checks in non-production builds. It will either not be run at all (as might be default behaviour when running an application without appropriate flag to enable them) or do nothing (since true is true, so it passes). It will not end the test with a positive result, it will not tell you it happened, it doesn't even count as test assertion. You might want to add some logging there, as without knowing an exception you didn't expect was thrown any number of shenanigans can slip by. Or even better, don't catch exceptions in tests. If unexpected exceptions get thrown you want the test to fail anyway right?

As to your direct problem it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the entire test class (I can see three mocks in your code - `jdbcTemplate`, `mockDao` and `ps`, only one of which is initialized as a Mock in the code you've given us, you only stub `jdbcTemplate` and from what I can tell without running the code it looks correct). Either the problem is somewhere you haven't shown us, or exception is thrown during stubbing of `jdbcTemplate`, causing that to not finish and fail leaving mock in invalid state.

Also worth noting, most of your code in doAnswer method is irrelevant. Even if you call real `batchInsertAll` that in turn will call `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` with some parameters, and your mock will return updateAllCounts array. doAnswer() line of methods is useful only if you need to change what your mock returns based on input arguments, otherwise you do some useless calculations you could have done wrong and end up with same result as `.thenReturn(updateAllCounts)` would.